# Does launching more then one web container on a single docker host make sense?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, docker, containers

Say there is an application powered by docker.

There could be containers for database, redis, etc and actual web containers (in my case it is php-fpm & nginx). Alternatively, it could be a purely web node with only web containers running.

My question - is there any benefit to have more then one such web container (php-fpm & nginx) on a single host? Would it increase performance? Could it decrease performance?

Comment: Only if your containers are resource-limited. Also, why are you running nginx and php-fpm in the same container?

Comment: They are in separate containers, i simplified the setup for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely to increase performance, unless each of your containers is constrained in the resources it can utilise, either by application configuration (eg. an insufficient number of `php-fpm` workers) or by the container itself (CPU or RAM limitations).

The main benefit that multiple web containers on a single physical machine provides is *redundancy*.  You can do a rolling restart of your web containers, with a load balancer in front to detect failures, and have zero-downtime upgrades.

Comment: Yes, rolling updates are exactly why i set it up to allow several web containers to be running at the same time, was wondering if it could be useful for anything else.